# Clicking the submit button submit the form data multiple times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have asynchronously loaded form. When I submit the form by clicking the submit button, it submits multiple times. I have gone through some of the SO answers but still the problem is there.

Form:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="aproveForm" class="smart-form" novalidate="novalidate">
    <fieldset>                              
        <section class="col col-5" >
            <select class="form-control" name="groupid" onchange="loadInvoice(this.value);">
                <option value="1">Sales</option>
                <option value="2">Merchandiser</option>
           </select>
       </section>                               
    </fieldset>         
</form>
```

JS

```
function loadInvoice(id){
    nid= 'id='+id;
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',                            
        url:'loadform.php',
        data:nid,
        dataType:'html',
        success:function(data) {
          $('#payform').html(data);                                 
        }
    });     
  }
```

in the `<div id="payform">`, I have loaded the form from loadform.php which is like below:

```
<form method="POST" id="mulpayment">
    <table class="table table-bordered" style="width:80%;">
        <tr>
            <th><div align="center">Name of Customer</div></th>
            <th><div align="center">New Payment</div></th>
            <th><div align="center">Total Debit</div></th>          
        </tr>
    <?php   
     alldebt=0;
     foreach($linvoice as $row): ?>
            <input type="hidden" id="gcustomer" name="gcustomer[]" value="<?php echo $row['customerid']; ?>">               
            <?php
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><div align=left>".$row['name'].".</div></td>";
                echo '<td><input type="text" id="gpay" name="gpay[]" min="0" required style="width:100%;"></td>';
                echo '<td align="right"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i> '.$row['totaldebit'].'</td>';                 
            echo "</tr>";
            $alldebt += $row['totaldebit'];
          endforeach; 
    ?>  
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3"><div align="right">Total</div></th>
            <th><div align="right"><i class="fa fa-inr"></i> <?php echo number_format($alldebt,2); ?></div></th>                
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
                <div align="right">
                    <input type="submit" id="savePayment" value="Save Payment" class="btn btn-success">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
  </form>
```

When I submit the form, it submits multiple times,i.e., paymentupdate.php runs multiple times. I want to run paymentupdate.php one time only. How do I solve this problem? Please help.

```
$(document).on("submit", "#mulpayment", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var gcustomer = $("input[id='gcustomer']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
            var gpay = $("input[id='gpay']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
            var gbalance = $("input[id='gbalance']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
            var gid = $('#gid').val();
            var paymentMade = 'gcustomer='+gcustomer+'&gpay='+gpay+'&gbalance='+gbalance+'&gid='+gid;
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                dataType:"json",
                data:paymentMade,
                url: 'paymentupdate.php',
                success:function(data) {
                    if(data.success){                       
                      $('#mulpayment')[0].reset();    
                      $('#payform').html(data.record);
                    }else{
                        alert(data.msg);                        
                    }                         
                }
              });
            return false;
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change button `type="submit"` for `type="button"`:

```
$(document).on("click", "#mulpayment", function(e){
            var gcustomer = $("input[id='gcustomer']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
            var gpay = $("input[id='gpay']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
            var gbalance = $("input[id='gbalance']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
            var gid = $('#gid').val();
            var paymentMade = 'gcustomer='+gcustomer+'&gpay='+gpay+'&gbalance='+gbalance+'&gid='+gid;
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                dataType:"json",
                data:paymentMade,
                url: 'paymentupdate.php',
                success:function(data) {
                    if(data.success){                       
                      $('#mulpayment')[0].reset();    
                      $('#payform').html(data.record);
                    }else{
                        alert(data.msg);                        
                    }                         
                }
              });
          });
```

And remove `action` and `method` attributes from the form tags, you dont need it if you use ajax:

```
<form id="aproveForm" class="smart-form" novalidate="novalidate">
<form id="mulpayment">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding disable to your button after submitting your form. like for example

```
$(document).on("click", "#mulpayment", function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
            $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
            var gcustomer = $("input[id='gcustomer']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
            var gpay = $("input[id='gpay']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
            var gbalance = $("input[id='gbalance']").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
            var gid = $('#gid').val();
            var paymentMade = 'gcustomer='+gcustomer+'&gpay='+gpay+'&gbalance='+gbalance+'&gid='+gid;
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                dataType:"json",
                data:paymentMade,
                url: 'paymentupdate.php',
                success:function(data) {
                    if(data.success){                       
                      $('#mulpayment')[0].reset();    
                      $('#payform').html(data.record);
                      $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);

                    }else{
                        alert(data.msg);                        
                    }                         
                }
              });
          });
```

in this way, it can prevent from clicking multiple times. you can enable back the button once the ajax request succeeds.